# Scheduling apex class

Tags: salesforce

I have a class.Class contain a method ParseJSONResponse().I want that method should get executed on daily basis at midnight.How I can achieve this in salesforce.
I know there is schedule apex mechanism is available in salesforce to perform such a thing but I need no. of steps or code to achieve this.I am new to salesforce.Any help would be appreciated.

```
  public with sharing class ConsumeCloudArmsWebserviceCallout{    
  public void ParseJSONResponse(){
// handling customerList and inserting records for it 

  DateTime lastModifiedDate =Common.getSynchDateByDataObject(CloudArmsWebserviceCallout.DataObject.CustomerContact);      
  List<Account> lstAccounts = ConsumeCustomers.CreateCustomers(lastModifiedDate);     
  ConsumeContacts.CreateContacts(lastModifiedDate);      
  Common.updateSynchByDataObject(CloudArmsWebserviceCallout.DataObject.CustomerContact);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and welcome to salesforce development.

If I assume something wrong let me know. So you are looking to

- Every Day at Midnight
- Fire a job that makes a callout to another system
- Then Parses the results and creates stuff

You are looking for Apex Scheduler code: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm

```java
global class ConsumeCloudArmsWebserviceCallout_Job implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        new ConsumeCloudArmsWebserviceCallout().ParseJSONResponse();
    }
}
```

Then you can schedule the job in yourname -> Developer Console. Debug -> Open Execute Anonymous Window.

```
system.schedule('Consumer Cloud Arms Service', '0 0 0 * * ?', new ConsumeCloudArmsWebserviceCallout_Job());
```

Keep in mind:

- you can only make 5 callouts in one apex transation. Meaning if you need to do more, you need to use a batch job or @future calls.
- Be careful with large data sets, if your job is expensive (creating and modifying lots of data) you need to be sure that you don't run in to CPU limits, So a batch job requesting smaller portions of data from the service you are calling out may be needed.

I don't think you will be running in to those issues, but they will catch you off guard sometimes.

EDIT: fixed the call to a new object, less psudo-code

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the Schedulable interface directly to your ConsumeCloudArmsWebserviceCallout class:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

In order to perform callout -which apparently you will according to your class name- you can use the Queueable interface:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm

```
public with sharing class ConsumeCloudArmsWebserviceCallout implements Schedulable {    
    public void ParseJSONResponse(){
        // handling customerList and inserting records for it 
        DateTime lastModifiedDate =Common.getSynchDateByDataObject(CloudArmsWebserviceCallout.DataObject.CustomerContact);      
        List<Account> lstAccounts = ConsumeCustomers.CreateCustomers(lastModifiedDate);     
        ConsumeContacts.CreateContacts(lastModifiedDate);      
        Common.updateSynchByDataObject(CloudArmsWebserviceCallout.DataObject.CustomerContact);
    }

    //Method implemented in order to use the Schedulable interface
    public void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        ConsumeCloudQueueable cloudQueueable = new ConsumeCloudQueueable();
        ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(cloudQueueable);
    }

    //Inner class that implements Queueable and can perform callouts.
    private class ConsumeCloudQueueable implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
        public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
            ConsumeCloudArmsWebserviceCallout cloudArms = new ConsumeCloudArmsWebserviceCallout();
            cloudArms.ParseJSONResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

Then go onto the class page on Salesforce setup.
There you will find a schedule class button.
You will be able to schedule all classes implementing the Schedulable interface.

What will happen is that it will schedule your class daily.
Then your schedule will only en-queue a ConsumeCloudQueueable class that will do the job whenever Salesforce runs it (pretty much straight away).
Once the job runs, it will execute whatever is on you ParseJSONResponse() method.

Let me know if you have any question.

Cheers,

Seb